# Getting min value from column and a string in another column associated with it using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

So I know that in order to get the minimum value in a column I can used df["column name"].min() but how would I go about getting a string in another column associated with that minimum value?

```
import pandas as pd 

# Creating the dataframe  

df = pd.DataFrame({"age":[4, 5, 2], 
                   "name":['mary, 'bob','sam'], 
                   "gender":['unknown', 'boy', 'girl']})
```

for instance, I am trying to get the name of the youngest child and store it to a variable and the gender of that child and store it to a variable

Comment: By "associated" what do u mean? So a little example of your dataframe and some clarification

Comment: Use the index. Use `idxmin()` to get the index, and use `loc` on that index to get the row

Comment: @WasifHasan I have added a bit more information. Hopefully it clarifies

Comment: @rafaelc I have an example above

Comment: As I said, you can do `df.loc[df.age.idxmin(), 'name']`

Comment: I am getting the following error: AssertionError: Series Expected type <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>, found <class 'str'> instead . Is there a way to do this by getting the min age first then the gender that has that value? @rafaelc

Answer (score -1):

I think that what you need is something like this:

```
df.loc[df.age.idxmin(), df['gender']]
```

That should output `girl`.
The logic behind it is pretty simple, with `idxmin()` you are getting the index of the minimun age, and then adding the column name just after that will give you the value of that row in the column you specified before.

Comment: I am getting the following error: AssertionError: Series Expected type <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>, found <class 'str'> instead . Is there a way to do this by getting the min age first then the gender that has that value?

Comment: Of course, maybe try with something like this instead: `df.loc[df.age.idxmin(), df['gender']]` I think would work nice.

Comment: If this answer helped you maybe you should consider accepting it as a valid answer so that others can learn from it too.

Comment: `df.loc[df.age.idxmin(), df['gender']]` Is not valid code at all